# How to fix ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: while installing pygame?

Tags: python-3.x

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGIIl.png)

I was trying to install pygame but I had gotten an error. I found out some people had the same problem with me but I could not find a way to solve it. I would be grateful if anyone could give an explanation on how to solve it. (I am quite new to python coding)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Post your error as a text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install the latest version of pygame with a non-compatible version of python. Your current python version is 3.9, try installing an earlier version of python and a [compatible version](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/PythonVersions) of pygame:

```
pip install python==3.8.3

pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

Should work.